# python rename all files in folder

Tags: python-3.x

I have files in folder with following example format:

`2020-02-4–1-11-17131-SERVER-4-10.1.1.1.txt`

I want to rename all files with this format in folder to following (remove ip address from end of the file:

```
 2020-02-4–1-11-17131-SERVER-4.txt
```

I want to do this using python.

Comment: Use ```shutil.move(src, dst)``` to "move" the files using a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The solution below is a relatively robust one that updates the files when they match the pattern and leaves them alone if they do not:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

pattern = re.compile('(.+)-(\d+\.){4}txt')
for file in Path('/path/to/folder').glob('*.txt'):
    m = pattern.match(file.name)
    if m:
        new_file = file.with_name(m.group(1) + ".txt")
        file.rename(new_file)
```

Comment: it throws error: 'AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'with_stem'

Comment: Sorry I didn't check the documentation to see that `with_stem` was just added in Python 3.9. See my updated answer